# How to make N Lists to fill with data?

Tags: python

I have a huge (2gb) mixed Log file which I want to split/group by the CMS, which made the log entry.

Now I run over the whole file and filter for different CMS Tags and export all Logs grouped by CMS Tags.

As I know, how many CMS I got, I can easy make the correct amount of Lists to fill: eg: 
`all_wordpress_logs = []`
all_cms2_logs = []
...
and fill that with `all_wordpress_logs.append(x)`

So far so good.

Now I want to group/filter by the class, which trown something that get logged.
But as I dont know how many lists I need, I cant prepare them like above. 
So my question is, how can I create Lists "on demand" with correct names to fill in with data? 
E.g:

```py
wordpress_class1 = []
wordpress_class1.append(x)
wordpress_class2 = []
wordpress_class2.append(x)
...
wordpress_classN = []
wordpress_classN.append(x)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a dictionary might be a better structure for your problem, but we'll need to see more code to really help you

Comment: dictionary is your friend.

Comment: You can make a list of lists and keep adding new lists to that.

Comment: [`dict.setdefault(CMS, []).append(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary, where the keys are the classes you want to group by, and when there is a new list, you just create and fill it then add it to the suitable key.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a good storage tool here where you dont know what classes you might have. It can expand easily and you can have lists inside it mapped to keys. Below is just an example of this. You can then access your lists by the class name.

```py
data="""class1 some log info
class1 more log info
class2 other log info
class3 different log into
class1 last log info
"""

dynamic_lists = {}
for line in data.splitlines():
    line_data = line.split()
    class_name = line_data[0]
    if class_name in dynamic_lists:
        dynamic_lists[class_name].append(" ".join(line_data[1:]))
    else:
        dynamic_lists[class_name] = [" ".join(line_data[1:])]

print(f'lines logged for class1 are: {dynamic_lists["class1"]}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
lines logged for class1 are: ['some log info', 'more log info', 'last log info']
```